# WildFly 10 Deployment Issues

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, wildfly-10

I am using an archetype from Maven called `"spring-mvc-webapp, 1.0.0CR8"` in my eclipse project. Infact i have not done anything to the project yet. I just want to deploy it and test it with the default application that comes with the archetype.  I have spent hours trying to fix it but with no success

I call my application from the browser like `localhost:8080/myapp` and i get **forbidden** in the browser. But when i go to **localhost:8080** i see the default home page of wildfly. When i go also to the management console of Wildfly, i see that my app is deployed yet it is not working.

Any idea to fix it is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the console log for something like `Registered web context: /myapp`. That will be the context you need to use.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The registered web context is : /myapp which displays at the console, yet it is not working.

Comment: I don't know anything about that archetype, but you may want to ensure you have some kind of index.html or index.jsp page.